# A problem with fetching data from the database in dynamically generated drop-down lists

Tags: php, jquery

I have a table that contains a row with the ability to generate other dynamic rows. The drop-down list works now in every new row that is created. I have the first row. The drop-down list that carries data from the database works well and the data is shown in it well, but when adding a new dynamic row and when Clicking on the drop down list the values written on it all show with the word Undefined all the values of the drop down list written on it show up with the word : Undefined I am really stuck any suggestions would be appreciated and thanks

php code:
`

```
<td class="td"><select class="form-control select_acount" name="account[]"required>
                            <option value="">--الحساب--</option>
                            <?php
                            $query = "select * from sah7atmain_acouts WHERE company like '".$multi."'";
                            $result = mysqli_query($con,$query);
                            $data = array();
                            if($result)
                            {
                              while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
                              $data[] = $row;
                            ?>
                            <?php echo '<option value="'.$row['acount_mounte'].'">'.$row['acount_name'].'</option>'?>;
                            <?php
                            }
                            } else{
                            }
                            ?>
                            </select>
                          </td>
```

`jquery code:`

```
var data = '<?php echo $data; ?>';
      var product_dd = "";
          product_dd += '<select class="form-control select_acount" name="account[]"required>';
          product_dd += '<option value="">--الحساب--</option>';
      if(data.length > 0){
        for(let i = 0; i < data.length; i ++) {
          product_dd += `<option value="${data[i]['acount_mounte']}">${data[i]['acount_name']}</option>`;
        }
      }
         product_dd += "</select>";
      
      var i = 0;
      $("#add-btn").click(function() {
        ++i;
        
        $("#dynamicAddRemove").append('<tr><td class="td">'+product_dd+'</td> <td class="td"><input type="number" name="debtor[' + i + ']" id="fname"class="form-control debtor arabicNumbers" onkeydown="return event.keyCode !== 69" required></td> <td class="td"><input type="number" name="creditor[' + i + ']" id="james" class="form-control creditor arabicNumbers" onkeydown="return event.keyCode !== 69" required></td> <td class="td"><input type="text"  name="description[' + i + ']" class="form-control"  required></td> <td> <input type="text" name="mount[' + i + ']" class="form-control mount"   required> </td><button type="button" name="add" class="btn btn-danger remove-tr"><i class="fas fa-trash-alt"></i></button></td></tr>');
      });
      $(document).on('click', '.remove-tr', function() {
        $(this).parents('tr').remove();
      });
```

`

Comment: How does the array `data` looks like in javascipt?

Comment: var data = '<?php echo $data; ?>';
      var product_dd = "";
          product_dd += '<select class="form-control select_acount" name="account[]"required>';
          product_dd += '<option value="">--الحساب--</option>';
      if(data.length > 0){
        for(let i = 0; i < data.length; i ++) {
          product_dd += `<option value="${data[i]['acount_mounte']}">${data[i]['acount_name']}</option>`;
        }
      }
         product_dd += "</select>";                 <td class="td">'+product_dd+'</td>

Comment: why you just posted the code from your question? People need to know what your data variable looks like